# SQL returns empty tuple even when data is available in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xml

I use a XML file to load a data into a database via php. Because the xml file has a lot of utf8 characters, i used the following SQl commands to alter my table to accept UTF 8 chars:

```
ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

i was successfull in entering the data, however the names in the database show up in a weird way. Example:

```
Jääskeläinen shows up as JÃ¤Ã¤skelÃ¤inen
```

Also, for normal names like `Jones` , if i use the query `select 'name' from players where 'name' LIKE '%n%';` the result set is `0` which is incorrect. I can only search via the `pid` ex: i get the result `Jones`  if i use the query `select 'name' from 'players' where`pid`= 453;`

Can someone explain to me as to why i am getting this error?

XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding ="utf8"?>
<pages>
<link>
<name> Cech </name>
<club> Chelsea </club>
<points> 49 </points>
</link>
```

php code to load XML file and enter data into database is [here](http://pastie.org/8538243)

Comment: Hoping someone responds.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue via php because basically i was retrieving and manipulating data via php. Right after i set the connection in my php file using:

```
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
```

put the following.

```
  mysql_set_charset('ISO-8859-1',$conn);
```

note the charset is set to `ISO-8859-1` and not to `utf8`.